# Connection to MS SQL Server database closes when application starts c#

Tags: c#, sql, database

Every time i attempt to debug my c# application i start the connection by right clicking on the server explorer but as soon as the application starts the connection closes again (get the red disconnection symbol) and i cannot seem to keep it open. Not sure why this is happening and im sure its nothing to do with the code that has been written as this has only recently started happening.

I think this is also causing another problem i am having where data is not being inserted into the database when an insert command is run.

Comment: Don't mistake the connection in Visual Studio from the connection used by your application's process. They are not at all related. The Server Explorer connection in Visual Studio is just for exploration and maintenance tasks on the database like setting up tables or adding default data. Certain modes of Sql Server only allow one connection at a time, and so Visual Studio _must_ disconnect in order for your applications process to make it's own connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow those steps:

1. Start SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Open the SQL Server Network Configuration's node.
3. Click on the Protocols for MSSQLServer as listed above.
4. Then in the right hand pane enable TCP/IP.
5. Now double click TCP/IP to get a dialog window.
6. If you want to listen on all the IP addresses for the server Select Yes in the Listen All box on the first Protocol tab; otherwise
7. Select the IP Addresses tab and enable the desired IP addresses by setting Enabled to Yes.

Comment: I would suggest revising your answer. It's incomplete and "as listed above" really doesn't direct anybody to anything usable.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution works for me.

Comment: Not saying that it won't work - I'm saying your answer doesn't help as it stands because it doesn't tell him where to reach the initial settings

Answer (score 0):

Forgot I hadn't answered this. As Joel suggested, what i was seeing in the Server Explorer where the connection seemed to fail was just the Server Explorer behaving as it should and not the actual problem. The problem with data not being inserted was just a problem with my insert statement. CHECK YOUR STATEMENTS.